# transform a function into a simple query

Tags: sql-server

I have the following function that returns parcel's delay:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Delay]
(@DeliveryTime int, @DeliveryHour int = 0, @Product_ID int, @Country varchar(2), @ZipCode varchar(10)
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @Delay int, @Guaranteed Int, @MaxDeliveryTime int, @MaxHour int, @test int

if @Country = 'FR'
    begin
        select  top 1 @Guaranteed = pz.TProduct_Guaranteed, 
                @MaxDeliveryTime = pz.TProduct_delay, 
                @MaxHour = pz.TProduct_HourMax
        from    TProductZone PZ 
        where   (pz.Country_ID = '0' OR pz.Country_ID = cast(@Country as varchar(2)))
                And (Zone_ID = '0' or Zone_ID = left(@ZipCode,2))
                And p.tproduct_id = @Product_ID
        Order by pz.country_id desc, zone_id desc
    end
Else
    Begin
        select  top 1 @Guaranteed = pz.TProduct_Guaranteed, 
                @MaxDeliveryTime = pz.TProduct_delay, 
                @MaxHour = pz.TProduct_HourMax
        from    TProductZone PZ 
        where   (pz.Country_ID = '0' OR pz.Country_ID = cast(@Country as varchar(2)))
                And (Zone_ID = '0')
                And p.tproduct_id = @Product_ID
        Order by pz.country_id desc, zone_id desc
    End

if @Guaranteed = 1
    Begin
        if @DeliveryTime >= @MaxDeliveryTime
            Begin
                set @Delay = @DeliveryTime-@MaxDeliveryTime
                if @DeliveryHour > @MaxHour
                    begin
                        set @Delay = @Delay+1
                    end
            End
        else
            Begin
                set @Delay = 0
            end
    End
Else
    Begin
        set @Delay = 0
    End 

return @Delay

END
```

This function is used as following:

```
Update  TShipping
    Set     Delay = Delay(S.TShipping_Deliverytime, cast(left(isnull(TD.Tracking_Hour,0),2) as int), S.TProduct_ID, S.Country_Code, S.ZipCode)
    From    TShipping S
            inner Join TrackingEndDelay TD On TD.TShipping_ID = S.TShipping_ID
    WHERE   IsNull(TShipping_Delivered,0) = 1
            And DateDiff(day,TShipping_Date,getdate()) < 90
```

I want to transform this function (and the call of the function) in a unique simple query in order to decrease the response time.

This is the query I did:

```
Update  TShipping
    Set     Delay =
case 
    WHEN TProduct_Guaranteed=0 or (TShipping_Deliverytime - TProduct_delay < 0) then 0
    WHEN (TShipping_Deliverytime - TProduct_delay >= 0) and cast(left(isnull(TD.Tracking_Hour,0),2) as int)  <= isnull(TProduct_HourMax,24) then TShipping_Deliverytime - TProduct_delay
    when (TShipping_Deliverytime - TProduct_delay >= 0) and cast(left(isnull(TD.Tracking_Hour,0),2) as int)  > isnull(TProduct_HourMax,24) then TShipping_Deliverytime - TProduct_delay +1
end
from    tshipping TS 
inner Join TrackingEndDelay TD On TD.TShipping_ID = TS.TShipping_ID
left join dbo.TShipping_DateInDelivery DID on ts.tshipping_id=DID.tshipping_id 
 outer apply  (select   top 1 pz.TProduct_Guaranteed, pz.TProduct_delay, pz.TProduct_HourMax
        from    TShipping S
                inner join TProductZone PZ on S.tproduct_id = pz.tproduct_id
        where   (pz.Country_ID = '0' OR pz.Country_ID = S.Country_Code)
                And (Zone_ID = '0' or (Zone_ID = left(S.TShipping_ZipCode,2) and S.Country_Code='FR'))
                and TS.TShipping_ID=S.TShipping_ID
        Order by pz.country_id desc, zone_id desc) r1
WHERE   IsNull(TShipping_Delivered,0) = 1
And DateDiff(day,TShipping_Date,getdate()) < 90
```

The problem is that I increase the response time instead of decreasing it. Has someone another better way to do it faster??

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: Rather than just pasting all of your code in to the post, it would be more useful if you add some sample data along with the desired output and the basic logic used to create it. As it stands, very few people will be willing to wade through your SQL to try to work out what it's doing before suggesting alternatives.

Comment: Please provide with the sample data